I'm getting SSL Certificates error in my Python Virtual Environment and I'm unable to fix it
I'm getting this error in my virtual env on Visual Studio Code.
(venv_x86) aryandaga@Aryans-MacBook-Pro-2 AI-DJ % allin1 data/audio_samples/ATMOSPHERE\ -\ FISHER\ x\ KITA\ ALEXANDER.mp3
=> Found 0 tracks already analyzed and 1 tracks to analyze.
=> Found 0 tracks already demixed, 1 to demix.
Downloading: "https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/demucs/hybrid_transformer/955717e8-8726e21a.th" to /Users/aryandaga/.cache/torch/hub/checkpoints/955717e8-8726e21a.th
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1454, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1075, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages/demucs/separate.py", line 219, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages/demucs/separate.py", line 133, in main
    model = get_model_from_args(args)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages/demucs/pretrained.py", line 96, in get_model_from_args
    return get_model(name=args.name, repo=args.repo)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages/demucs/pretrained.py", line 76, in get_model
    model = any_repo.get_model(name)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages/demucs/repo.py", line 148, in get_model
    return self.bag_repo.get_model(name_or_sig)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages/demucs/repo.py", line 130, in get_model
    models = [self.model_repo.get_model(sig) for sig in signatures]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages/demucs/repo.py", line 130, in <listcomp>
    models = [self.model_repo.get_model(sig) for sig in signatures]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages/demucs/repo.py", line 65, in get_model
    pkg = torch.hub.load_state_dict_from_url(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 766, in load_state_dict_from_url
    download_url_to_file(url, cached_file, hash_prefix, progress=progress)
  File "/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 620, in download_url_to_file
    u = urlopen(req)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/bin/allin1", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages/allin1/cli.py", line 53, in main
    analyze(
  File "/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages/allin1/analyze.py", line 118, in analyze
    demix_paths = demix(todo_paths, demix_dir, device)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages/allin1/demix.py", line 30, in demix
    subprocess.run(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 569, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/venv_x86/bin/python3.11', '-m', 'demucs.separate', '--out', '/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/demix', '--name', 'htdemucs', '--device', 'cpu', '/Users/aryandaga/AI-DJ/data/audio_samples/ATMOSPHERE - FISHER x KITA ALEXANDER.mp3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
(venv_x86) aryandaga@Aryans-MacBook-Pro-2 AI-DJ % pip install --upgrade certifi
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in ./venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2024.7.4)

And I checked online and found one of the ways is to go to open Application/Python3.11/Install Certificates.commmand
When doing that I'm getting this in my terminal. I've been trying to figure out how to resolve this issue but I'm unable to find any solution.
/Applications/Python\ 3.11/Install\ Certificates.command ; exit;
 -- pip install --upgrade certifi
Collecting certifi
  Using cached certifi-2024.7.4-py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
Installing collected packages: certifi
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/certifi'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.


[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3 -> 24.2
[notice] To update, run: pip3 install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 44, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 24, in main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11', '-E', '-s', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'certifi']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

Here are more details that might be needed which I'm providing. This is from my local terminal.
aryandaga@Aryans-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % python3 --version
Python 3.11.0
aryandaga@Aryans-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % pip --version
pip 24.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
aryandaga@Aryans-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % pip install --upgrade certifi
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (2024.7.4)


You should have run the Install Certificates script from your (venv_x86) virtual environment. Instead, just ignore that tool and pip install certifi from your virtual environment.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I have already tried upgrading and installing certifi in my virtual env but it keeps telling me that Requirement already satisfied: certifi in ./venv_x86/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2024.7.4). Could there be an issue with the API I'm using and maybe it has outdated SSL Certificates.

There are multiple possibilities. At this point I would guess the most likely is that the server being contacted is using a certificate that is either self-signed or signed by a home-grown CA. I would be using tools like Wireshark and others to see what server is being contacted and what certificate is being presented.

Try to check your python interpreter, this may be caused by incorrect python environment.

There is a mismatch between your python and pip - 3.11 vs 3.10. Try installing certifi with python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade ceritifi. You can also run the Install Certificates command with sudo, although installing Python packages as a superuser is generally not recommended
